# What is dotnet5.4 and net451 in class library?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dnx

In aspnet 5 I created a project which came with `dotnet5.4` and `net451`. Since it's a class library I assume it does not need the runtime so uses `net451` instead of `dnx451` (my wild guess). But what about `dotnet5.4` what exactly is that for ?

Comment: to really understand it I recommend watch this video on channel9 https://channel9.msdn.com/events/ASPNET-Events/ASPNET-Fall-Sessions/Class-Libraries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** With [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx) announcement, the monikers will probably change again. This answer is only scoped to the release of RC1. Any release further than RC2 won't apply here.

Basically, `dnxcore50` became `dotnet5.4` and `dnx451` became `net451`.

Those were temporary to begin with and were bound to change prior to the final release.

Most of this information can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98

Comment: Furthermore, I find that a lot of dependencies have no moved away from `dnxcore50` yet, so I have to target both `dnxcore50` and `dotnet5.4` in my own libraries if I want to use them in other projects that can only target `dnxcore50` right now.

Comment: You are right. All core projects by Microsoft will have moved with the latest RC. Other external packages? It will take some time.

Comment: Save my nervous system. How many more renames are to be expected. K DNU KVM DNVM CoreFX CoreCLR CLR DNXCore50 DotNET5.4 DNX451 NET451. Anyway thank you for clarifying..

Comment: It should be the last one.

Comment: It is not the last one. They will rename "dotnet5.4" to something "NETPlatform1.3" and the DNU/DNVM/DNX command lines to "dotnet" command line. History: K stuff was prototyping, dnx/dnu/dnvm was finishing from ASP.Net team and the new dotnet thingy is the generalization from the .Net Core team (instead the asp.net team).

Comment: but the announcement says 'only class libraries' should use `net451`. now I'm even more confused. should I always use `net451` or keep `dnx451` for non-library projects

Comment: Dnx/dotnet for those built on the new stack. net451 for old applications.

Answer (score 3):

> But what about dotnet5.4 what exactly is that for ?

From [Announcing ASP.NET 5 Release Candidate 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx):

> With this version of ASP.NET 5 templates, the “Class Library (package)” project template will target “dotnet5.4” which has binary compatibility with .NET 4.6, .NET Core 5, and Mono.