# The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could not be found Asp.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roslyn

I have a simple class like this

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Common
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string Description(this Enum value)
        {
            FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
                false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                return attributes[0].Description;
            }

            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this compile error -

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

My project.json is

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Common Class Library",
  "authors": [ "bryan" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried many things like adding dependencies and frameworkAssemblies for  various versions of System.Component and System but not have worked.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2065) tells me that it might not be available on CoreClr

Comment: But I'm using net451 and dotnet5.4, not dnxcore5.0. I'm finding all this very messy

Comment: dotnet5.4 appears to be one of the CoreClr project types. Shot in the dark: try removing it if you're just supporting windows and want to use .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: I want to target dotnet5.4. The project this class is in is part of a bigger solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DescriptionAttribute not available in DNX Core 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847442/descriptionattribute-not-available-in-dnx-core-5-0)

Comment: What is the difference between "dotnet5.4" and "dnxcore50" ? Confused about this.

Comment: `dnxcore50` became `dotnet5.4`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183141/what-is-dotnet5-4-and-net451-in-class-library/34185201 (Don't worry, you're not crazy, this is super confusing) If you don't need to do cross-platform, you should be able to remove the `dotnet5.4` entry and I think it should work.

Comment: I don't need cross platform, but this library will be referenced by a asp.net 5 web app. If I want the web app to run on just iis what frameworks should I have in the project.json?